# Twilio text message in to a voice mail

Tags: c#, twilio

Did anyone have example code to convert text message in to a voice mail using Twilio in c#?  I have found sample code on http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-text-to-speech which uses PHP but I don’t have any background on PHP if someone have a sample code in c#, it will be best for me to understand how to convert text message in to voice mail using Twilio easily. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

So just to make sure I understand what you want to do, you want to let a user submit an HTML form with some text, that you then have Twilio call and read.  This is really easy to do.

Start by creating an input form the way you normally do in an ASP.NET WebForm.  In the forms postback you use the [Twilio .NET helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) to initiate an about outbound phone call:

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient("[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]","[YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]");
var result = client.InitiateOutboundCall("[FROM_NUMBER]","[TO_NUMBER]","[URL]");
if (result.RestException!=null) {
    //the call to the twilio rest api failed
}
```

Notice that one of the parameters for the InitiateOutboundCall method is called [Url](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#url-parameter?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).  This is a URL that Twilio will request once the called person answers their phone and is your opportunity to use [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) to tell Twilio how to proceed with the live phone call.

For your scenario I can think of two ways to do this.  The easiest way is simply to use the [Simple Message twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/message?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon), which will create a URL that tells Twilio how to generate the TwiML needed to say your message:

```
string url = "http://twimlets.com/message?Message[0]=" + this.txtMessage.Text;

var client = new TwilioRestClient("[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]","[YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]");
var result = client.InitiateOutboundCall("[FROM_NUMBER]","[TO_NUMBER]",url);
```

You of course can also generate your own TwiML directly in your application using the Twilio TwiML Helper library.  To do this create another WebForm and use its Page Load event to generate and return the TwiML:

```
var response = new TwilioResponse();
response.Say(this.txtMessage.Text);

response.ContentType = "text/xml";
response.Write(response.ToString());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your codes somehow help me to convert the PHP code to c#. But the main problem is how to convert a text message from the browser to a voice mail on a phone number. If you have more information on this, it will help me a lot.
Thanks

Comment: Sure, happy to help out.  So to clarify, you want to let someone enter some text into a form in the browser, then have Twilio call someone and Say that message to them?  Am I understanding your scenario correctly?

Comment: and also I am not using MVC …I am using WebForms.

Comment: This is why I love Twilio! Intuitive, powerful and great support!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help the voice mail works perfectly.

Comment: +1 on Twimlets! I've been looking for a way to do this for days. I've somewhat figured it out with Twiml... but none of the tutorials walk you through how to post dynamic text... it's always static! Why Twiml anyway? With this day and age you should just be able to post your text with an API call... I really never understood the need for the Twiml layer for posting. I do however understand the need for receiving calls/ messages but for posting you should not need Twiml.